# How do I simplify the square root of a negative number squares?

Tags: square-numbers

How would I simplify $\sqrt{h^2}$, where $h$ is a negative number?  The answer key says $-h$ but I don't understand the answer.

Comment: Imagine h is -5. $\sqrt{(-5)^{2}} = \sqrt{25} = 5 = -h$. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $h$ is negative, then $-h$ is positive and $h^2=(-h)^2$. Thus
$$
\sqrt{h^2} = \sqrt{(-h)^2} = -h,
$$
where the second equality follows because $\sqrt{p^2}=p$ whenever $p$ is positive.

In general, we have $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, where
$$
|x| := \begin{cases}
x & \text{if}\ x\geq 0 \\
-x & \text{if}\ x<0.
\end{cases}
$$